# Vue propiedades dinámicas mediante botones

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, props

Tengo unos componentes padre/hijo que se comunican mediante propiedades. Ambos los estoy llamando en la misma vista, la información que necesito mostrar en el componente que recibe la propiedad (componente hijo) depende del botón que se seleccione en el componente padre, pero en este momento, solo recibe la propiedad vacía.

**HTML del componente padre:**

```
<button 
    class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block" 
    @click="setDataResident" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#personPropertyRelation"
>
    Agregar Residente
</button>

<button 
    class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block" 
    @click="setDataOwner" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#personPropertyRelation"
>
    Agregar Propietario
</button>
```

**JavaScript del componente padre:**

```
props: ['property'],
    data() {
        return {
            success:null,
            dataRelation: {
                'title':null,
                'placeholder':null,
                'label':null,
                'id_inmueble':this.property.id,
                'propietario':null,
                'residente':null,
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setDataResident: function() {
            this.dataRelation.title='Relacionar Residente';
            this.dataRelation.placeholder='Ingrese el id del Residente...';
            this.dataRelation.label='Residente';
            this.dataRelation.residente=true;
            this.dataRelation.propietario=false;
        },
        setDataOwner: function() {
            this.dataRelation.title='Relacionar Propietario';
            this.dataRelation.placeholder='Ingrese el id del Propietario...';
            this.dataRelation.label='Propietario';
            this.dataRelation.propietario=true;
            this.dataRelation.residente=false;
        },
    },
}
```

**Invocación del componente hijo:**

```
<person-property-component :dataRelation="dataRelation"></person-property-component>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías situar el código del componente hijo?

Answer (score 1):

En el código que has situado no parece estar el problema, así que el error debe venir de la organización de los elementos o del código del componente hijo en sí. Sin verlo todo es difícil detectar dónde tienes el error (es por eso que normalmente se pide [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Pero quizás un pequeño ejemplo te ayude a encontrar tu error. Observa el siguiente *snippet* (que al parecer es el patrón que estás siguiendo). Observa cómo se le pasa al componente hijo la propiedad `misDatos` como parámetro (al igual que haces con `dataRelation`) y como el hijo representa los datos contenidos en dicho objeto sin ninguna dificultad:

```js
Vue.component('componente-padre', {
  template: '#componente-padre-template',
  data () {
    return {
      misDatos: { numero: 0 }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sumar() { this.misDatos.numero++; },
    restar() { this.misDatos.numero--; }
  }
})

Vue.component('componente-hijo', {
  template: '#componente-hijo-template',
  props: ['misDatos'],
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```css
.padre {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hijo {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="componente-hijo-template">
  <div class="hijo">
    <h4>Hijo</h4>
    número: {{ misDatos.numero }}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="componente-padre-template">
  <div class="padre">
  
    <h4>Padre</h4>
    
    <button @click="sumar">Suma</button>
    <button @click="restar">Resta</button>
    
    <componente-hijo :misDatos="misDatos">
    </componente-hijo>
    
  </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <componente-padre></componente-padre>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no encuentro error alguno. Ayudaría si tienes alguna captura.
Otra forma de pasar un objeto a un componente hijo es mediante `v-bind="dataRelation"`, al hacer esto envias cada una de las propiedades del objeto por separado y en tu componente hijo tendrias que acceder mediante el nombre de cada propiedad, ejemplo: `props:['title','placeholder','label']`

No es incorrecta la forma en que envías el objeto y no deberías tener problema alguno pero es recomendable hacerlo como el ejemplo arriba.
Fuente: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object